# "Awaiting EO Processing" for 2 weeks after submission. Should I contact?

Tags: journal-workflow

I recently submitted an article to a relatively well-known academic journal in information system.

The journal uses ScholarOne.

After the initial submission, the status of my article has been shown as "Awaiting EO Processing" for more than 2 weeks.

Should I contact the journal at this moment?

Comment: I'm aware of many posts on "when to ask the status" for journal submissions. But most of them are issues _during/after_ review process. So I would like to ask this.

Comment: It might just be that the editor cannot find reviewers who are willing to read your manuscript. I would give it a month in total and then ask politely.

Comment: @George I think it is the editorial office searching for an editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the journal, two weeks isn't really a long time for editor assignment. Your manuscript might be at the end of a pretty long queue that might take time. Moreover, getting the right editor for your topic is also sometimes an issue.

Another point to note is that ScholarOne is not always up-to-date with the process of the publisher. This may also depend on the frequency of updates sent from the publisher's editorial office to ScholarOne.

In my experience with ScholarOne, I had *"Editor now searching and inviting referees"* for about a month before I received the review result, *"Resubmit [with minor edit]"*. There was no *"under review"* status in between. Hence, there was nothing to worry about.

If this is prolonged over a month, you may send a polite request for the current status of your manuscript through ScholarOne helpdesk. They are very helpful in this regard and usually reply within a day or two.

Comment: As you suggested, my submission moved in "Under review" after 25 days of "Awaitng EO Processing" Thanks!

Comment: @Pengin Hi. The same happened to me as well. From "EO Processing" to "Under Review". Can u let me know what exactly "Under Review" meant in your case? Was it the case of editorial review or the case of external peer review? Would be helpful if u let me know.